# How to set border color to the edge pixel in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

In order to prevent artifacts when scaling sprites or displaying them on not full pixels in my graphics engine of choice I have a need to go through all my sprites and add an edge to each one of them. The edge needs to be of the color of the neighboring pixels, just like this:

[image: Expected effect]

The left image is the original image and the right one is the expected result.

**Is it possible to achieve this effect in ImageMagick?** In other words, can you expand the image in all four directions by one pixel, copying the edge pixels into the newly added border?

Answer (score 4):

First, you should be aware about the following basic image operations, which will serve as building blocks to the full command:

1. `image.ext[NxM+x+y]` will cut out an `NxM` pixels-sized area from *image.ext* that is offset by `+x` pixels to the right and `+y` pixels to the bottom, calculated from the top left corner.
2. `+append` appends two (or more) images *horizontally*.
3. `-append` appends two (or more) images *vertically*.
4. `image.ext[1x+0+0]` cuts off the left-most column of pixels in an image.
5. `-flop` will mirror an image from left to right.
6. `-flip` will mirror an image from top to bottom.
7. `image.ext[x1+0+0]` cuts out the top-most row of pixels in an image.
8. `image.ext[1x+0+0]` cuts out the left-most column of pixels in an image.
9. `-crop NxM+x+y` does the same as `1.`.
10. `mpr:ABC` will write an image into a *Magick Persistent Registry*, using the label *ABC*. From an MPR, which resides in a special memory location, ImageMagick can retrieve a copy of the image simply by invoking the label name.
11. `-delete 0` will delete the image with index 0 from the current image sequence.
12. `+write` will write the image sequence under the name given.
13. `+repage` normalizes the image canvas again.

Now you can combine `5.` with `8.` to cut out the right-most row of pixels:

```
-flop image.ext[1x+0+0]
```

You can also combine `6.` with `7.` to cut out the bottom-most column of pixels:

```
-flip image.ext[x1+0+0]
```

Now combine these effects with the *parentheses* syntax `\( ... \)` for side-processing of images for the complete command:

```
convert image.png                     \
  -respect-parentheses                \
  +write mpr:ABC                      \
  -delete 0                           \
    \( mpr:ABC[1x+0+0] \)             \
    \( mpr:ABC \)                     \
    \( mpr:ABC -flop -crop 1x+0+0 \)  \
  +append +repage                     \
  +write mpr:XYZ                      \
  -delete 0                           \
    \( mpr:XYZ[x1+0+0] \)             \
    \( mpr:XYZ \)                     \
    \( mpr:XYZ -flip -crop x1+0+0 \)  \
  -append +repage                     \
  extended-edges.png
```

Applying this to the builtin `rose:` image:

```
convert rose:                         \
  -respect-parentheses                \
  +write mpr:ABC                      \
  -delete 0                           \
    \( mpr:ABC[1x+0+0] \)             \
    \( mpr:ABC \)                     \
    \( mpr:ABC -flop -crop 1x+0+0 \)  \
  +append +repage                     \
  +write mpr:XYZ                      \
  -delete 0                           \
    \( mpr:XYZ[x1+0+0] \)             \
    \( mpr:XYZ \)                     \
    \( mpr:XYZ -flip -crop x1+0+0 \)  \
  -append +repage                     \
  extend.png
```

### Quick-check size of new image

```
identify rose: extend.png 
 rose:=>ROSE   PPM 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 9.67KB 0.000u 0:00.000
 extend.png[1] PNG 72x48 72x48+0+0 8-bit sRGB 7.11KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

### Check, if the top 2 rows of pixels are identical

**Top-most row:**

```
convert extend.png[x1+0+0] txt:- | md5sum
 12b639cd1606559633ee23a062ae42a6  -
```

**Second row from top:**

```
convert extend.png[x1+0+1] txt:- | md5sum
 12b639cd1606559633ee23a062ae42a6  -
```

**Third row from top:**

```
convert extend.png[x1+0+2] txt:- | md5sum
 88fc6f9bac3f8ab4cbf2374fbef6fcf0  -
```

### Check, if the two left-most columns are identical

**Left-most column:**

```
convert extend.png[1x+0+0] txt:- | md5sum
 4d2223b74901f9ce1fb4456dacb4315c  -
```

**Second column from left:**

```
convert extend.png[1x+1+0] txt:- | md5sum
 4d2223b74901f9ce1fb4456dacb4315c  -
```

**Third column from left:**

```
convert extend.png[1x+2+0] txt:- | md5sum
 07794b4423f5b6515142d15a5c652743  -
```

I'm not showing how to check if two bottom-most rows and two right-most columns are also identical...

---

<sub>There is also a way to achieve the same effect by using the `-virtual-pixel edge` operation, but it is more difficult to understand...</sub>

Comment: Wow... This is amazing! I'll try to give it a try in a minute. Since I need only to increase the edge by one pixel I thought about achieving it by drawing the original image first in the four corners, then in the center of the four edges and then, finally, in the center but I can only do the most basic imagemagick operation.

Comment: @MaurycyZarzycki: And? Did you give it a try?

Comment: WARNING:  The `[1x+0+0]`-thing (point 4. above used on row 5 in the code) is always producing an 1x3px image for me. Solve the issue by using `-crop 1x+0+0` instead since that works as expected. `[x1+0+0]` seems to be working correctly though. I'm running ImageMagick 6.9.7-4.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to tackle this is to resize the original image to be 2 pixels taller and 2 pixels wider than the original, and then to avoid distortions in the interior pixels, composite the unchanged original picture back on top in the centre.

So, to get the dimensions of the output image, by adding 2 to width and height,

```
geom=$(identify -format "%[fx:w+2]x%[fx:h+2]" sprite.png)
```

that gives something like

```
34x34
```

if the original image is 32x32.

Then I resize the image to this new size to fill the border pixels and composite the unchanged original back on top

```
convert sprite.png -resize $geom -gravity center sprite.png -composite out.png
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not so sure if this algorithm works *reliably* to produce the wanted results. Most likely it works "good enough" in most cases, and deviations won't be easily discoverable to the human eye, but...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Hi Kurt. Can you maybe explain your fears please? I presume you concede that the inner pixels will be perfect with my method since they are a direct copy of the original image, so it is just the 1 pixel edge that you have concerns about. I consider resizing a very *reliable* operation, so could you spell out what you are thinking please? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can see one real issue and one potential. The real pproblem would be if you tried to make the edge more than 1 tile wide (which, for most cases, won't be needed). And potentially, if the scaling used smoothing, the neighboring tiles may affect the color of the target edge and it might create a bit different colors. But simply disabling smoothing will make it work correctly.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the question about any neighbouring tiles, nor about the possibility of the extension being by more than a single pixel... but I hope the method works well enough for your needs. Good luck!

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Of course, the inner pixels will be perfect with your method. I just doubt that the border pixels will be "cloned" as 1:1 copies. The `-resize` operator implicitely applies `-filter lanczos` (if not set otherwise), which will apply some maths when calculating the color values of additional pixels. -- I'll still have to find the time to come up with an example where the deviation is obvious. But of course I concede that your method will be a very good approximation in any case. A black border pixel will not suddenly turn white with it  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using Virtual Pixels:

```
convert -resize "%[fx:w+4]x%[fx:h+4]" "./input.png" -set option:distort:viewport "%[fx:w+4]x%[fx:h+4]"-2-2 -virtual-pixel Edge -distort SRT 0 +repage ./output.png
```

`input.png` is the input image. `output.png` will have it's border extended by 2 pixels with the colors of the original edge. The image is resized by adding twice the extended width. The viewport offset is set to extended width.

See [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/misc/) for more information.